# R: Can't use paste0 function within a for loop

Tags: r, loops, paste

I have a vector and I want to add a "0" at the beginning of each string if the original string has less than 3 characters.

```
for(i in 1:93){
  if(nchar(a[i]) < 3){
    paste0("0", a[i])
  }
}
```

If I run the code above, I get a "NULL" as result.
The weird thing is that if I run the code without the for loop (I mean individually) everything goes fine.

```
  if(nchar(a[11]) < 3){
    paste0("0", a[11])
  }
```

If you have a clue about what is happening it would be very helpful for me. Any other way to approach this problem is also very welcomed.
Thanks for your time and help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need a loop here.  This can be done with `sprintf` directly on the vector

```
sprintf('%03d', a)
```

---

In the loop, there was no assignment to the original vector element and no `print`, thus it didn't return anything

```
a <- as.character(a)
for(i in 1:93){
  if(nchar(a[i]) < 3){
    a[i] <- paste0("0", a[i])
  }
}
```